# Excel Open 2 Workbooks at the same time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I open with vba coding.  There are several different userforms to input data and get reports out of this workbook.

It seems that while this workbook is open, and active, I cannot open, to look at and/or edit, an unrelated excel spreadsheet through Windows Explorer. One of my users asked me if while this program is running if she could look at (without closing the active workbook) a different spreadsheet.  It has nothing to do with coding such a request into the active workbook, its more for convenience i.e. not having to close this one and open that one.

Is there anything I can do to facilitate this request?  Is there some vba code I can use in my active workbook that allows or gives Excel permission to open more than one workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find it is when a Userform or any other Excel dialog-based object is open, then you cannot simply "double-click" on an another workbook to open, as Excel is busy and focus on the open dialog screen.

However, if you start another instance of Excel (Start -> All programs -> Microsoft Excel) and then open the workbook from within the new instance, then you work with additional workbooks.

Comment: That was easy enough.  Thank you, joehanna.  Its exactly what I needed.